# How to do links on formula,using tagpdf features?

Tags: cross-referencing, luatex, expl3, links, tagpdf

As we know,we can write:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq1} 
x^x=1
\end{equation}
\ref{eq1}
```

But if we want to do tagging of formula,link not shows in pdf. How i can do reference on structure element of formula,for example if i define it as:

```
\def\[#1\]{
\begin{equation}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P,alttext-o=\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
#1
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\end{equation}
}
```

But how to create a link on object on structure tree,which have alttext,using tagpdf features? Yes,probably zref allow to do it (i am not sure in it),but even if it do this,i probably can reference on mc object,but not in structure. And even i can reference on mc object,i dont know,how to do it. So i need in example,which shows,how to do links on mc and structure elements,created by tagpdf package. Thanks everybody very much for any help.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I got your question right, but why don't you use just a macro with two arguments, one for the content and one for the tag? Like: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\taggedequation}[2]{
\begin{equation}\label{eq:#2}
    #1
\end{equation}
}
\begin{document}
\taggedequation{x^2 + y^2 = z^2}{mytag}
Reference on \ref{eq:mytag}
\end{document}`

Comment: @@Nico But in this case i probably haven't link on element with formula in structure tree.